# How to deal with model values that are specific to a parent via a relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model "Group" which owns "GroupMember" models via a HasMany relationship.

The "GroupMember" has an attribute "isAdmin" which indicates if that member is an admin of the group.

When i view a list of "GroupMember" ember-data tries to refresh those items from the API with a GET request of /groupMembers/{id} for each item.

The problem is i have no idea what group that member is being refreshed for in order to set the "isAdmin" value. It seems like the request should be /group/{group_id}/members/{member_id}.

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense. Im having trouble wording it. Let me know what i can do to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

it does make sense. One solution you can do is to use query params to pass the information about member id and the group. Then, your request could look like that:

```
GET /groupMembers?id=:id&group=:groupId
```

Then it works more like a filter.

To achieve that, instead of using standard `this.store.find('group', id)` you can use this:

```
this.store.find('groupMembers', {
  id: id,
  group: group
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is basically what i was looking for but theres an issue. Im not making a call to load the group members. They are all loaded with the group and then when i goto that view Ember refreshes those records on its own so i have no chance to add the group/groupId. 

Do you know how i can modify the request in that instance?

Comment: so when you are going to a certain route, then Ember is syncing the model with your backend, is that a case? what do you want to achieve? can you post more of your code? GroupMember route/controller/view and tell what behaviour you want to achieve?